# How long should I wait before getting involved with hiring/ interviewing for vacancies at my company?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I'm interested in helping interview others, because I enjoy interacting with people and also setting a higher standard at my company. However, I am relatively new, and one of the HR staff had said its a 'little early', which is quite vague.

How many months after joining should I wait before interviewing or testing others?

EDIT: I meant software/ technical interviews, and assumed they would be the same as normal interviews.

Comment: What is your position in the company?

Comment: Months? None. If you're in a position to be interviewing people then you'd be doing so at the companies discretion. If not then you do the tasks you're paid to do.

Comment: Sorry, when I said interview, I meant technical interview, as I am a software engineer. Other software engineers also do these, sometimes once a week.

Comment: They were actually asking everyone in public, which was what caught my interest.

Comment: @Kilisi it seems like you have a traditional mindset of working; you might work in a large bureaucratic environment. We have the opportunity to add a lot more value than just the 'job'. This depends on the company size and management.

Comment: @BenButterworth Kilisi doesn't have a "traditional" mindset. Unless you work for yourself, you work at the pleasure of your employer. They will have the best understanding about when THEY want you to assist with interviews. The best thing you can do is make indicate your interest to whomever is responsible for your professional development, and ask to develop some sort of training to make this possible.

Comment: 'They will have the best understanding about when THEY want you to assist with interviews.' Maybe in your company and experience, but in my role they are actively looking for people to contribute to technical interviews. I was simply asking how long I should wait, not seeking 'permission' because I don't think im 'worthy' enough, and that I should wait to be 'called up' for the 'honour'. It looks like thats what you prefer. What does 'THEY' even mean, someone in the HR team who organises this initiative?

Comment: 'The best thing you can do is make indicate your interest to whomever is responsible for your professional development, and ask to develop some sort of training to make this possible.' Yes, that is what I am asking. how long do I wait before I 'indicate my interest'. I think Kilisi means I should work and wait to see if 'THEY' would think I could do it, without being proactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm interested in helping interview others, because I enjoy interacting with people and also setting a higher standard at my company.

This seems like a bit of a non-sequitur - interacting with someone "normally" is very different to interacting with them in an interview setting. You're trying to (in a very limited timeframe) form an accurate assessment of their skills, work out if they'd be a good fit for the team, and determine how much you think their experience is worth financially. You need to do all of that whilst, ideally, remaining polite and friendly to put them at ease (ie. not just barking questions at them one after the other.)

It's a very particular skillset that a lot of people (sadly even people that do this job on a regular basis!) aren't very good at.

> However, I am relatively new, and one of the HR staff had said its a 'little early', which is quite vague.

I assume you've not been assigned to a managerial type role where it'd normally be your job to interview candidates, otherwise this would be weird. If you're the engineering manager, CTO, even lead developer of a team and they don't want you getting a look-in at anyone who would be working under you, they may have misunderstood your role.

Assuming the above isn't the case, then it's deliberately vague as there's no set timescale (or no guarantee it would ever be appropriate.) If you're a more junior or mid-level dev then it's unlikely they'd ask you to be on the interview panel unless:

- You've proven yourself to be one of the experts in a particular framework / library / technology, and they want to explicitly hire people to work with it;
- You're leaving after a while, and they want you to help interview your replacement;
- As above, but instead of leaving you're being promoted to a more senior position;
- You've shown yourself to be a good mentor and interact well with new hires, they'd like that to continue, and therefore they want you to form an opinion of potential new hires;
- They're down a person and want to draft "anyone" else in.

As above, there's no set timescale for any of that to happen. Your best bet if you really want to take part in interviews is to work your way up to a senior position quickly where you'll be drafted in to help as a matter of course - but in isolation, that would be a bit of an unusual career motivator!

Answer (score 5):

Many teams ask "individual contributors" (corpspeak for non-managers) to participate in the interview process. I suggest you give some thought to how that benefits the parties involved. Here are some reasons I've done it.

- the candidate is introduced to some possible future co-workers and can assess whether she'll fit in.
- ... and vice versa.
- positive interactions between candidates and their future co-workers are great recruiting tools.
- if the job requires particular skills, sometimes a co-worker is in a good position to assess the candidate.
- it's part of a company culture of group decision making and widespread buy-in to major decisions like who to hire.

HR people usually follow the lead of hiring managers about who participates in the hiring process.

With respect, it's almost never done so junior employees can take it on themselves to "set a higher standard." If that's your core reason to do it, I agree it's too early. In fact, promoting that kind of organizational change requires deep relationships and great patience. You would be wise to get to know people and be patient to change standards.

Still, a person such as yourself can answer candidates' questions about what it's like to join your company, so that's a good reason.

I suggest you let your hiring manager know you're interested in being part of their interviewing process. Ask, respectfully, for a chance to participate.